# Add ranking "on the fly" based on ORDER BY Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I've used something similar to the below to take the result from a mySQL query and add a "rank" based on where the row from the result falls in the response.

```
$service_url = 'https://something.html?';
   $curl = curl_init($service_url);
   $curl_post_data = array(
        "q" => "SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 Rank, q.* FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r,(SELECT something, another, thing from my_database order by something) q",
        "api_key" => 'XXX',
        );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
   $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
 echo $curl_response;
```

When I take out all my attempts to add the rank, this runs fine. But now I'm getting an error echoed back: `{"error":["syntax error at or near \":=\""]}`

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Without understanding the receiving end of this, it looks simply like its trying to add := into the SQL query. The error is here: "SELECT @rownum :=

Comment: you're not doing a mysql query. you're doing a curl request to some url. what exactly is happening on that server with this query string you send across? We can't help you, since you're not talking to mysql directly, and you've provided NO information about this api at all.

Comment: 1) *never* run SQL defined in a parameter.
2) all the query you have up there seems to do is add a row number... You can easily just use a counter on PHP side (or just use the array's index if you fetched the entire dataset) to show which row you are at. No need for complex non-standard SQL.

Comment: Also, you've tagged this question with both the `mysql` and `postgresql` tags. Those are completely different. Please remove the one that does not apply.

Comment: In postgresql you can get row ranking using `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` window functions.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Ended up going with this suggestion. Much simpler than what I was thinking. Thanks.